# How does the Iron framework apply a tuple of modifiers to Response::with?

Tags: rust, iron

I am looking into the Iron source code for `Response::with()`, trying to understand how it applies a tuple as modifiers to the response.

As I understand, a modifier is simply a builder object, taking in a reference to the current context (`self`) and taking the object you wish to build on as a parameter (as long as you implement the `modify` function).

Assuming we have the following code:

```
use iron::modifiers::Header;

fn hello_world(_: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
    let string = get_file_as_string("./public/index.html");
    let content_type = Header(ContentType(Mime(TopLevel::Text, SubLevel::Html, vec![])));
    Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, string, content_type)))
}
```

Digging through the docs, I can see the implementation of `Response::with()` in Iron is as follows:

```
pub fn new() -> Response {
    Response {
        status: None, // Start with no response code.
        body: None, // Start with no body.
        headers: Headers::new(),
        extensions: TypeMap::new()
    }
}

/// Construct a Response with the specified modifier pre-applied.
pub fn with<M: Modifier<Response>>(m: M) -> Response {
    Response::new().set(m)
}
```

I'm struggling to see how my tuple of objects are translated into modifiers? I'd expect to see a foreach potentially iterating over each modifier, but here I simply see a set operation.

Could somebody explain the order to execution here and uncover what is actually happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting question! Let's look at the function signature again:

```
fn with<M: Modifier<Response>>(m: M) -> Response
```

This means that `with` accepts exactly one argument that implements `Modifier<Response>`. So next [we could look up](http://ironframework.io/doc/modifier/trait.Modifier.html) what types do implement the trait `Modifier`. In the documentation we see that it's not only implemented for `String` or `Status`, but for tuple types, too! Those implementations are written in [this file](https://github.com/reem/rust-modifier/blob/42b30e4953ea68a5471cb3145bcb4ea05b156792/src/impls.rs). For example, let's look at this impl:

```
impl<X, M1, M2, M3> Modifier<X> for (M1, M2, M3)
    where M1: Modifier<X>,
          M2: Modifier<X>,
          M3: Modifier<X> 
{
    fn modify(self, x: &mut X) {
        self.0.modify(x);
        self.1.modify(x);
        self.2.modify(x);
    }
}
```

This implements the trait for every tuple of size 3 which elements also implement `Modifier`. And the implementation of `modify` is just to call the `modify`-implementation of each tuple element; this is the *foreach* you were searching for.

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant response, is there any reason why 'Modifier' implements tuples up to 5 and not beyond?

Comment: My guess is that it is just annoying to type too much trait implementations

Comment: @JacobClark Basically what aochagavia says. The problem is that Rust doesn't offer functionality to implement a trait for tuples of all sizes. So each implementation has to be written out manually (more or less) and adds more code to the project. So you have to stop at some point... Iron decided 5 is a good point to stop ;)